# How can a batch file receive two values from a VB Script?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wsh

The VB script takes one parameter as input. Is it possible to enter two parameters? Also could I use drop down list as well in the below script?

```
@echo off

> usermessage.vbs ECHO WScript.Echo InputBox( "Enter parameter1", "para1", "xxxxxxxx" )
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('CSCRIPT.EXE //NoLogo usermessage.vbs') DO SET para1=%%A

ECHO para1= %para1%

DEL usermessage.vbs
```

Comment: typo mistake. it should read ECHO Para 1 is = %para1%

Comment: you can use `set /p "var="` to get input in the batch but your vbs script needs work to use them.

Comment: You could arrange for the VBScript to write as many SET commands as you like into a temporary batch file, and then `call` that batch file from the main batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps is this what you want?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 > usermessage.vbs ECHO WScript.Echo InputBox( "Enter parameter1", "para1", "xxxxxxxx" )
>> usermessage.vbs ECHO WScript.Echo InputBox( "Enter parameter2", "para2", "yyyyyyyy" )
>> usermessage.vbs ECHO WScript.Echo InputBox( "Enter parameter3", "para3", "zzzzzzzz" )

set i=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('CSCRIPT.EXE //NoLogo usermessage.vbs') DO (
   set /A i+=1
   SET para!i!=%%A
)

ECHO para1= %para1%
ECHO para2= %para2%
ECHO para3= %para3%

DEL usermessage.vbs
```

Comment: Is it possible all three parameters options would be availabel on the ONE dialog box.

Comment: I googled for "Visual Basic InputBox" and found this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w(v=vs.71).aspx The InputBox function can only get one parameter at a time...

Comment: ok.  May be I need to look for a customised input box/dialog box for this.

Comment: Good luck with that! You may review this site: http://www.script-coding.com/dynwrapx_eng.html

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
InputBox( "Enter parameters separated by a space", "params", "eg1 eg2 eg3" )
```

Then split that input.